# Magento 2: How to add custom block after the add to cart [Custom Theme]

Tags: product, magento2.3, layout, blocks, xml

I want to add a block after add to cart but this code doesn´t work:

```
app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
    
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="product/view/form.phtml">
    <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
           <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
           
           <!--THIS BLOCK--> 
           <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.cuidados" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/cuidados.phtml"/> 
           <!--===========-->

    </container>

</block>
```

What is the problem??

Thankss

Answer (score 1):

> app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
            <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
                 <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.cuidados" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/cuidados.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>

        <move element="custom.cuidados" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.extrahint"/>
    </body>

</page>
```

Hope this will help you..!

Answer (score 0):

You can add **following code** in your theme file : **app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- another code lines -->
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.cuidados" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/cuidados.phtml" after="product.info.addtocart"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
<page>
```

Thank you
Hiren Patel

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work. The code does not appear on the product page. What could be happening?